# All browsers regularly hang connecting to websites. Internet confirmed working perfectly

Tags: windows-7, windows, dns, browser, internet

Multiple times per hour my browser will just hang for 30+ seconds when connecting to any website. Tested with IE, Firefox and Chrome.

My computer is running Windows 7 and i have a Cisco VPN installed for connecting to my work environment.

When sites start hanging i have tried all 3 browsers and all 3 hang. 
I am still however able to ping any websites. All websites hang in browsers.

Chrome for example will just say "connecting..." in the bottom left corner.

Any ideas of the cause of this?

**UPDATE**

So my computer has McAfee Endpoint Security firewall installed. 
When this issue occurs if i disable the firewall then the webpage immediately loads. I dont know if mcafee is the cause or whether it just resets the connection when i disable the firewall.

Comment: Usually it's an issue with DNS resolving names ...

Comment: That's what I thought but pinging the host resolves fine so that means the DNS is fine.

Comment: Personally I'd just uninstall McAfee Endpoint Security. Windows 7 comes with a perfectly reasonable firewall which won't cause your browser to hang.

Comment: It's a business laptop, mcafee is mandatory by company policy.